# How does $\sum x_i y_i = \bar{x}\sum y_i$?

Tags: summation

This is the identity given in my textbook with regards to the centre of mass of  of a set of particles along the line. $x$ could be the distance along the line, and $y$ could be the mass. $\sum x_i y_i$ would then be the sum of moments of forces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *definition* of the centre of mass; more specifically, the centre of mass $\bar x$ is defined in this context by
$$
\bar x = \bigg( \sum x_i y_i \bigg) \bigg/ \sum y_i
$$
(the horizontal moment divided by the mass).

Comment: Ah I see. A confusing notation that clashes with statistics, where $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$.

Comment: If it helps, think of this formula as a generalization of the one from statistics, where all the "particles" (measurements) have the same mass $y_i=1$.